# Are there any records of Charlemagne's baptismal (ie. Christian) name?

Tags: middle-ages, christianity

Just like the title states, I am curious if [Charlemagne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlemagne) took on a baptismal name.

Comment: It seems unlikely. Before his baptism by the Pope in 774, he was already called Charles on his [coinage](https://cdn.globalauctionplatform.com/08c1d7e3-113a-4d88-ad63-a56200b02136/36553bb3-484d-4231-85fc-34219d24ca98/original.jpg). After his baptism, he was still known as Charles.

Answer (score 5):

Very little is known about the childhood of Charlemagne. There is no reason to believe that he was not baptized with any other name than that of Charles (Karl). In fact, we are not even sure as where he was born.

> Charlemagne’s Early Years
>
> Charlemagne was born around 742, the son of Bertrada of Laon (d.783) and Pepin the Short (d.768), who became king of the Franks in 751. Charlemagne’s exact birthplace is unknown, although historians have suggested Liege in present-day Belgium and Aachen in modern-day Germany as possible locations. Similarly, little is known about the future ruler’s childhood and education, although as an adult, he displayed a talent for languages and could speak Latin and understand Greek, among other languages. - [Charlemagne](http://www.history.com/topics/charlemagne)

Comment: *There **is no** reason to believe that he **was not** baptized with any other name than that of Charles (Karl).* - Did you mean to say that *there **is no** reason to believe that he **was** baptized with any other name than that of Charles (Karl),* or were you, on the contrary, implying that *there **is** reason to believe that he **was** baptized with another name than that of Charles (Karl)* ?